# Nuclear decay formula derivation

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, half-life

I don't understand why the nuclear decay formula is derived with logarithms.

if $t=T_{1/2}$ then

$N=N_0\cdot\frac{1}{2}$

if $t=2T_{1/2}$ then

$N=N_0\cdot\frac{1}{2^2}$

if $t=3T_{1/2}$ then

$N=N_0\cdot\frac{1}{2^3}$

and so on... so the formula can be expressed in this form

$N=N_0\cdot \frac{1}{2^{\frac{t}{T_{1/2}}}}$

$N=N_0\cdot 2^{-\frac{t}{T_{1/2}}}$

So why is it derived further with natural logarithms? why doesn't the derivation just stop there?

the next derivation is
$\ln \left(\frac{N}{N_0}\right)=\ln \left(2^{-\frac{t}{T_{1/2}}}\right)$

and finally

$N=N_0e^{-\frac{\ln \left(2\right)}{T_{1/2}}t}$

Comment: It really boils down to the convention one likes. These doubts are quite common when we are just beginning to study physics. The rule of thumb  is to express whatever you want in the standard convention (or your own liking, if it's not too wild :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decay graph can be described in a number of ways each with a parameter which is a characteristic of the decay.

Your description the characteristic parameter is the *half-life*, $\tau$ and so $N(t) = N_0\,2^{-t/\tau}$.

Another often used parameter is the *decay constant*, $\lambda$ which is the constant of proportionality in the assumption that the activity (rate of decay $\frac {dN(t)}{dt}$) is proportional to the number of undecayed nuclei $N(t)$, ie $\dfrac{dN(t)}{dt} \propto N(t) \Rightarrow \dfrac{dN(t)}{dt} =-\lambda\, N(t) \Rightarrow N(t)=N_0\,e^{-\lambda\, t}$

These two parameters which characterize the decay, decay constant and half life,  are related $\lambda \,\tau=\ln2$ and you will note that logarithms, $\ln \equiv \log_{\rm e}$, are involved when comparing parameters.

$N(\tau) = \frac {N_0}{2} = N_0\,e^{-\lambda\, \tau}\Rightarrow 2= e^{\lambda\, \tau}\Rightarrow \ln2= \ln \left(e^{\lambda\, \tau}\right )=\lambda \tau \ln e =\lambda \tau$.